# Automatically restart Neo4J or make it run forever?

Tags: neo4j, restart, pm2

I'm using an amazing `pm2` tool to run my `node.js` app in a production environment. It monitors and automatically restarts the app should something go wrong.

Is there something like this available for Neo4J? My database sometimes quits because the amount of memory on my WebFaction server is not sufficient at peak times, so while I'm fixing that I also want something solid that would restart my Neo4J database if it goes down.

Currently I use 2.0.3 version and I set up a crontab script to simply start it through bash every minute, but maybe there's a more elegant solution, especially in the newer versions of Neo4J? Or maybe something with the same monitoring capacities as `pm2` offers?

Answer (score 0):

A DB is very different from a web server. Web servers are typically implemented to be stateless, but the whole purpose of a DB is to be stateful.

When a DB fails, its state may not correct or usable any more, and may require some manual effort to repair. So, even if you could put in place something to automatically attempt to restart neo4j after a failure, the attempt may not work. And even if it does seem to work, you may have lost some data.

The main thing you need to do is to tune your DB installation so that is works well and has a very low probability of failing in the first place.